# NFS Share - trying to mount my Synology 1511+ NAS

Tags: nfs

I am running ubuntu 10.10 64 bit on my mac mini. After installing nfs-common, and attempting to mount using

`mount -t nfs4 -o proto=tcp,port=2049 192.168.1.139:/volume1/magneto/ ./test`

I keep getting this error:

`mount.nfs4: mounting 192.168.1.139:/volume1/magneto/ failed, reason given by server:
  No such file or directory`

When i run

```
showmount -e 192.168.1.139
Export list for 192.168.1.139:
/volume1/magneto *
```

It seems to indicate that the volume is there and that i'm typing the correct thing. I tried removing the trailing slash and no luck.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
I'm using this NAS: http://www.synology.com/us/products/DS1511+/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike NFSv3, NFSv4 hides the prefix of the exported path (the NFS root). The prefix is configured in the exports on the NAS.

Try:

```
mount -t nfs4 -o proto=tcp,port=2049 192.168.1.139:/magneto/ ./test
```

Or:

```
mount -t nfs4 -o proto=tcp,port=2049 192.168.1.139:/ ./test
```